# Adding name and history attribute to 2D particle simulation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, simulation

I am attempting to create a program which simulates particles colliding in a 2D box, but each particle is labeled with a random 5 character string name and each collision is tracked in a list along each particle. So after the simulation, I would like a list from each particle listing which particles it has hit. I have forked this great simulation https://github.com/xnx/collision and added the name and history attributes to the particle class. However, whenever I attempt to access .name or .history, my kernel dies. The output says:

```
Kernel died, restarting
    
Restarting kernel...
```

The failure happens in the handle_collisions function (line 197), or whenever I try to access the history or the name, so there must be something wrong in my implementation of the name and history attributes. I have also tried to instantiate name and history in the init_particles function instead of place_particles but that had the same results. I'm not exactly sure how to correctly implement them. Thanks for your help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib import animation
from itertools import combinations
import random
import string


class Particle:
    """A class representing a two-dimensional particle."""

    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, name, history, radius=0.01, styles=None):
        """Initialize the particle's position, velocity, name, history and radius.

        Any key-value pairs passed in the styles dictionary will be passed
        as arguments to Matplotlib's Circle patch constructor.

        """

        self.r = np.array((x, y))
        self.v = np.array((vx, vy))
        self.radius = radius
        self.mass = self.radius**2

        self.styles = styles
        if not self.styles:
            # Default circle styles
            self.styles = {'edgecolor': 'b', 'fill': False}

    # For convenience, map the components of the particle's position and
    # velocity vector onto the attributes x, y, vx and vy.
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.r[0]
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.r[0] = value
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.r[1]
    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self.r[1] = value
    @property
    def vx(self):
        return self.v[0]
    @vx.setter
    def vx(self, value):
        self.v[0] = value
    @property
    def vy(self):
        return self.v[1]
    @vy.setter
    def vy(self, value):
        self.v[1] = value
    @property
    def history(self):
        return self.history
    @history.setter
    def history(self,value):
        self.history=value
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    @name.setter
    def name(self,value):
        self.name=value

    def overlaps(self, other):
        """Does the circle of this Particle overlap that of other?"""
        return np.hypot(*(self.r - other.r)) < self.radius + other.radius

    def draw(self, ax):
        """Add this Particle's Circle patch to the Matplotlib Axes ax."""

        circle = Circle(xy=self.r, radius=self.radius, **self.styles)
        ax.add_patch(circle)
        return circle

    def advance(self, dt):
        """Advance the Particle's position forward in time by dt."""

        self.r += self.v * dt
        
class Simulation:
    """A class for a simple hard-circle molecular dynamics simulation.

    The simulation is carried out on a square domain: 0 <= x < 1, 0 <= y < 1.

    """

    ParticleClass = Particle

    def __init__(self, n, radius=0.01, styles=None):
        """Initialize the simulation with n Particles with radii radius. 
        Each particle is initialized with a 10 letter string name and an empty history.

        radius can be a single value or a sequence with n values.

        Any key-value pairs passed in the styles dictionary will be passed
        as arguments to Matplotlib's Circle patch constructor when drawing
        the Particles.

        """

        self.init_particles(n, radius, styles)
        self.dt = 0.01

    def place_particle(self, rad, styles):
        # Choose x, y so that the Particle is entirely inside the
        # domain of the simulation.
        x, y = rad + (1 - 2*rad) * np.random.random(2)
        # Choose a random velocity (within some reasonable range of
        # values) for the Particle.
        vr = 0.1 * np.sqrt(np.random.random()) + 0.05
        vphi = 2*np.pi * np.random.random()
        vx, vy = vr * np.cos(vphi), vr * np.sin(vphi)
        name = self.assignname
        history = []
        particle = self.ParticleClass(x, y, vx, vy, name, history, rad, styles)
        # Check that the Particle doesn't overlap one that's already
        # been placed.
        for p2 in self.particles:
            if p2.overlaps(particle):
                break
        else:
            self.particles.append(particle)
            return True
        return False
    
    def assignname(self):
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        name=''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(5))
        return name

    def init_particles(self, n, radius, styles=None):
        """Initialize the n Particles of the simulation.

        Positions and velocities are chosen randomly; radius can be a single
        value or a sequence with n values.

        """

        try:
            iterator = iter(radius)
            assert n == len(radius)
        except TypeError:
            # r isn't iterable: turn it into a generator that returns the
            # same value n times.
            def r_gen(n, radius):
                for i in range(n):
                    yield radius
            radius = r_gen(n, radius)

        self.n = n
        self.particles = []
        for i, rad in enumerate(radius):
            # Try to find a random initial position for this particle.
            while not self.place_particle(rad, styles):
                pass

    def change_velocities(self, p1, p2):
        """
        Particles p1 and p2 have collided elastically: update their
        velocities.

        """
        
        m1, m2 = p1.mass, p2.mass
        M = m1 + m2
        r1, r2 = p1.r, p2.r
        d = np.linalg.norm(r1 - r2)**2
        v1, v2 = p1.v, p2.v
        u1 = v1 - 2*m2 / M * np.dot(v1-v2, r1-r2) / d * (r1 - r2)
        u2 = v2 - 2*m1 / M * np.dot(v2-v1, r2-r1) / d * (r2 - r1)
        p1.v = u1
        p2.v = u2

    def handle_collisions(self):
        """Detect and handle any collisions between the Particles.

        When two Particles collide, they do so elastically: their velocities
        change such that both energy and momentum are conserved.

        """ 

        # We're going to need a sequence of all of the pairs of particles when
        # we are detecting collisions. combinations generates pairs of indexes
        # into the self.particles list of Particles on the fly.
        
        #particles share history when they collide
        pairs = combinations(range(self.n), 2)
        for i,j in pairs:
            if self.particles[i].overlaps(self.particles[j]):
                self.change_velocities(self.particles[i], self.particles[j])
                #FAILS HERE
                #self.particles[i].history.append(self.particles[j].name)
                #self.particles[j].history.append(self.particles[i].name)


    def handle_boundary_collisions(self, p):
        """Bounce the particles off the walls elastically."""

        if p.x - p.radius < 0:
            p.x = p.radius
            p.vx = -p.vx
        if p.x + p.radius > 1:
            p.x = 1-p.radius
            p.vx = -p.vx
        if p.y - p.radius < 0:
            p.y = p.radius
            p.vy = -p.vy
        if p.y + p.radius > 1:
            p.y = 1-p.radius
            p.vy = -p.vy

    def apply_forces(self):
        """Override this method to accelerate the particles."""
        pass

    def advance_animation(self):
        """Advance the animation by dt, returning the updated Circles list."""

        for i, p in enumerate(self.particles):
            p.advance(self.dt)
            self.handle_boundary_collisions(p)
            self.circles[i].center = p.r
        self.handle_collisions()
        self.apply_forces()
        return self.circles

    def advance(self):
        """Advance the animation by dt."""
        for i, p in enumerate(self.particles):
            p.advance(self.dt)
            self.handle_boundary_collisions(p)
        self.handle_collisions()
        self.apply_forces()

    def init(self):
        """Initialize the Matplotlib animation."""

        self.circles = []
        for particle in self.particles:
            self.circles.append(particle.draw(self.ax))
        return self.circles

    def animate(self, i):
        """The function passed to Matplotlib's FuncAnimation routine."""

        self.advance_animation()
        return self.circles

    def setup_animation(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        for s in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
            self.ax.spines[s].set_linewidth(2)
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
        self.ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
        self.ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])

    def save_or_show_animation(self, anim, save, filename='collision.mp4'):
        if save:
            Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
            writer = Writer(fps=10, bitrate=1800)
            anim.save(filename, writer=writer)
        else:
            plt.show()

    def do_animation(self, save=False, interval=1, filename='collision.mp4'):
        """Set up and carry out the animation of the molecular dynamics.

        To save the animation as a MP4 movie, set save=True.
        """

        self.setup_animation()
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate,
                init_func=self.init, frames=800, interval=interval, blit=True)
        self.save_or_show_animation(anim, save, filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nparticles = 20
    radii = .02
    styles = {'edgecolor': 'C0', 'linewidth': 2, 'fill': None}
    sim = Simulation(nparticles, radii, styles)
    sim.do_animation(save=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two immediate problems in your code.

First: you did add history as a `Particle.__init__` parameter but you never initialize the property itself.

Add something like this:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, name, history, radius=0.01, styles=None):
    
    self._history = history
```

And bigger problem: you have an infinite recursion in your @property definition:

```
@property
def history(self):
    return self.history
@history.setter
def history(self,value):
    self.history=value
```

So in your getter you called `history` you call itself `return self.history` which will loop itself until program will crash.

Rename internal property to `_history`:

```
@property
def history(self):
    return self._history
@history.setter
def history(self,value):
    self._history=value
```

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thank you, these were my issues.